# Can mypy infer the type of containers such as collections Counter

Tags: mypy, python-typing

Running this mypy gist (https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=58a8148f2c95c7a282a6f8a11ccd689a)

```py
from collections import Counter

C = Counter()
```

gives this mypy error:

```
main.py:3: error: Need type annotation for "C"  [var-annotated]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is there any way that mypy could infer this type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mypy does infer it if you initialize the `Counter` with some data. But if you don't want to pass anything in the initializer, you must give a type annotation to `C`, where you specify the generic type e.g., `C: Counter[str]`.

See this section in the mypy docs: [Types of empty collections](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#types-of-empty-collections)